# Declarations for the types used by Intel in the instrinsics guide?

Tags: x86, intel, sse, intrinsics

Where are the declarations for the types used by the Intel intrinsic functions, according to the [Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide)?

For example, [_mm_stream_si64](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_stream_si64&expand=5642) is defined as:

```
void _mm_stream_si64 (__int64* mem_addr, __int64 a)
```

However, after including `<immintrin.h>` on gcc on Linux, the type `__int64` does not exist.

Comment: GCC/clang's intrinsics are mostly compatible with ICC's documentation, but I think they don't provide that type.  IIRC, they use a normal `int64_t` instead for the declaration of intrinsics that Intel defines with `__int64`.

Comment: @PeterCordes that was the first thing I tried, but `int64_t` doesn't work either, because `mem_addr` in that function is declared as `long long *`, and you can't convert `int64_t *` to that (at least you can't if your compiler is strict). So it seems hard to write portable code here...

Comment: Oops, I knew it was some standard type.  Why can't you just use `long long`, then?  Is it not alias-compatible with `__int64` on ICC and/or MSVC?  It's portably 64-bit on all compilers that support Intel intrinsics, in 32 and 64 bit mode.  (64-bit `movnti` is only available in 64-bit mode, but possibly relevant for other intrinsics.  Although usually the ones that can do 64-bit things in 32-bit mode use `__m64`)

Comment: @PeterCordes - yeah I guess I can just use `long long` (that's what I'm currently doing anyway). My concern was say that on Windows something like `__int64` might be `long int` or whatever and then I'd have the reverse problem there. Of course it isn't, it seems to be `long long` there. It's a bit annoying you can't look at the guide and know what types to use though (why don't they just declare it as `long long` or at least define the types they use? seems Windows-centric).

Comment: Be careful with that; IIRC `__int64` is the same as `long` on Windows and most Linux machines, but it's `long long` on macOS.  The mismatch can cause some problems (for example, it bit me [here](https://github.com/nemequ/portable-snippets/commit/fb718fdaefd44e3172b4576ab3dfb6e94e1f1235)).  Basically the best thing you can do is just use the types Intel's (IMHO very poorly designed) API specifies, and cast as necessary so your API can use more reasonable types.

Comment: @nemequ - is `__int64` defined at all on Linux? I can't find it...